# DB2 Procedures return result set after for loop

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm currently on writing a SQL-Procedure on IBM i 5 V7R1. 
If I want to return a result set after my for loop I can't create the procedure. 
Here is the code:

```
create or replace procedure test1()
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    SPECIFIC EDVVAEH1.test1 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    MODIFIES SQL DATA 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
    ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
    COMMIT = *NONE , 
    DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
    DFTRDBCOL = *NONE , 
    DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
    DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
    SRTSEQ = *HEX   
    proc: BEGIN 
    DECLARE x VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE return_cur CURSOR with return  FOR 
        select * from sysibm.sysdummy1;
    loop1: for record as C1 cursor for 
        SELECT TABLE_NAME
        from qsys2.systables
    DO 
    SET x = record.table_name;
    END FOR loop1;
    open return_cur;
    END proc
```

---

As the options define, I want to return a result set after both loops, but it doesn't let me create this procedure. 

 The Error is -104 token: "End of Statement" is not valid, but everything is there :(

Comment: I'd suggest reviewing the SQL syntax...[DB2 for i SQL Reference 7.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzintro.htm)

Comment: I spent hours reading this...

Comment: How are you running the statement? When I run what you provided in iNav 'Run SQL Scripts', the only error I get is about the missing declaration for "X". If I add a DECLARE for X, it creates fine.

Comment: I will try it on monday, but we all at work have my problem.

Comment: I tried it with the declaration of X... Same problem. 
Vendor Code -104 ... End of statement not valid.

Comment: And yes, I'm using iNav with RUN SQL Scripts

Comment: Two elements to verify: First, what is the DB2 group PTF level on the server? And what is your System i Access version **and** service level on your PC?

Comment: Command WRKPTFGRP says SF99711 is installed. 
iAccess version is V7R1 and Modification Level is 0
I hope that are all information you'll need

Comment: Not "Modification Level", but "Service level". Service level comes from the System i Access 'Properties' page. This indicates what (if any) fix pack has been installed. And what is the "Level" for PTF SF99711? The DB2 group PTF is often refreshed with a new "Level".

Comment: Hey sorry I had holidays. 
If I go on properties page it says i5/OS version is V7R1 modification 0. The level of SF99711 is 2.

Comment: The current DB2 group level on i 7.1 is "PTF Group Level: 39", so you are way behind, essentially at the initial level from a few years ago. And I would guess that the System i Access Properties would should that the 'Service level' on your PC is just as far out of date. Those should be the first things handled whenever this type of problem arises.

Comment: Okay I will contact our Server Team anywhere in the world. Maybe they are so kind and install the new PTFs.

Comment: Just realized that you listed PTF SF99711, but the DB2 group PTF is **SF99701**. SF99711 is merely a list of the various available group PTFs for IBM i 7.1 (and its current level is "3").

Comment: Okay thanks SF99701 is at Level 32. So there is something missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found the root cause of my problem, but I can't fix it. 
As far as I can see, my i Access has a Problem with the for-statement. 
I copied the statement to my RDi 9.1 in the Database Development view and ran it there. I also set a different end of statement command and after that I was able to create my procedure.

Now I need to wait until someone in my company can provide me a PTF for the client access. I already tried to install all PTFs delivered with the IBM i, but no improvements ...

If anyone has an idea, where I can download a PTF for client Access please give me a hint. The IBM site is not possible for me since, I am not registered for out IBM i.

Thanks.

Comment: See [**Latest service packs for supported releases**](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows_sp.html) assuming you're running Windows. But if your server's DB2 group level is only "2", it seems very likely that the server may also be somewhat unreliable in itself.

Comment: I just realized that "2" isn't a meaningful level for your DB2 group. Wrong PTF number in an earlier comment, and I didn't notice until now.

Comment: Okay I found the right service packon the IBm ftp folder. From now on my client access is working and I know where to get the updates. Thank you all a million